# Cooperative multiple inheritance and python 2.7 mixins

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use the cooperative multiple inheritance pattern to resolve a problem. A very simplified version of my python 2.7 code looks like this:

```
class Base1(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def to_tuple(self):
        return self.a, self.b

    def to_string(self):
        return '%s.%s' % self.to_tuple()   # (1)

class Base2(object):

    def __init__(self, c, d):
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def to_tuple(self):
        return self.c, self.d

    def to_string(self):
        return '%s-%s' % self.to_tuple()    #(2)

class MyMixin(Base1, Base2):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        Base1.__init__(self, a, b)
        Base2.__init__(self, c, d)

    def to_tuple(self):
        return Base1.to_tuple(self) + Base2.to_tuple(self)

    def to_string(self):
        return '{}: {} '.format(Base1.to_string(self), Base2.to_string(self))


mix = MyMixin('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
print(mix.to_string())
```

After writing this code, I was expecting the result:

```
a.b: c-d
```

but the code fails. When the line `#(1)` is run, `self` is a `MyMixin` class, not a `Base1` class, so `to_tuple` returns 4 items.

The only way I've found to fix this is to replace the lines `#(1)` and `#(2)` above with:

```
return '%s.%s' % Base1.to_tuple()    # (1)
return '%s.%s' % Base2.to_tuple()    # (2)
```

and this feels terribly wrong for a number of reasons.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hrm. There's not really a clean way around that. `self.to_tuple()` will always call the overridden method (i.e. all methods are virtual) and the only way to say "I want the method from *this* class" is to explicitly name the class

Comment: try to read this article, you probably misunderstood the idea implementation in python:
http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=281127

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what happens. When `mix.to_string()` is called, first, it calls `Base1.to_string(self)` passing a `mix` instance as a self, which means when to_string is called on Base1 it has an instance of `MyMixin` which returns ('a','b','c','d') on `to_tuple` call. That's why it fails, cuz tuple contains 4 items and only 2 are required by line #1.

To solve this issue try to avoid inheritance from multiple classes with the same method signatures. Use composition instead.

```
class MyMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.base1 = Base1(a, b)
        self.base2 = Base2(c, d)

    def to_tuple(self):
        return self.base1.to_tuple(self) + self.base2.to_tuple(self)

    def to_string(self):
        return '{}: {} '.format(self.base1.to_string(), self.base2.to_string())
```